# Created a landing page as code resource for CSS in Marketing cloud Cloud pages. I need to find out the page ID for this page

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, cloudpage

I have created a code resource landing page to add the css styling in Cloud pages collection in marketing cloud.
 Where can i find the properties to see the page ID is not visible. I am just wondering where can i find the Page ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1. Classic Editor

Within CloudPages collection the page ID for CSS can be found by inserting the CSS resource into a landing page.

**Here are the steps involved:**

- First create a landing page through the **create** option within a collection.
  [image]
- Create CSS Code resource from the same **create** option.
- Then edit the landing page which was created in first step and on the left folder panel you can choose the **CSS** folder and you should be able to see the CSS file.
- Click the CSS file and then click on the editable section of the landing page. Hit the **insert** button to insert the CSS file in the landing page editor section.
  [image]
- You should see something like this `%%=CloudPagesURL(xxx)=%%` and **XXX** is the page ID for that CSS file.

### 2. Content Builder

[**Content Builder**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/cloudpages/cloudpages_editor/#Gears) is the new feature which has been added to the CloudPages. This is mainly focused on the inbuilt functionality to create web pages through the content block.

I have noticed limited customisation options with this feature. However, with some digging I have managed to add the Code Resource to the existing content blocks in the landing pages option.

**Steps**

- Drop your content block on the content area of the landing page and click on the block to edit.
- Then choose the **HTML Editor** option to view the html code. Also note that there are few dropdown options and one of them is called **Insert code snippet**. You will be able to reference the CSS which you uploaded to the landing pages through this option.

> Note: I strongly recommend using classic builder if you're applying
> custom CSS and JS to the page which give wider option than content
> builder.

[image]

Comment: Hi Brad, Thanks for the input i am using Contact builder instead of classic i am not able to see the resource option.

Comment: When i created a classic page and was able to do the above steps and got the page id.

Comment: @deepakreddy I have updated the original answer and please accept and vote my solution if it helps. Thank You